# Entity Framework one to many and many to one with same class type

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a Game model, in this model have 2 properties, HasDlc and IsDlc

```
public class Game
{   
    public bool HasDlc { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Dlc> Dlc { get; set; } 

    public bool IsDlc { get; set; }
    public virtual Dlc DlcFor { get; set; }
}
```

A game can either have dlc or it can be dlc (or both can be false, but both can never be true). A game can have many Dlc's, but a Dlc can only have one game.

Dlc is just another instance of a Game object. So if a game is DLC, i want it to associate with the game that it is Dlc for. If a game has Dlc, i want to get a list of games that make up its Dlc.

There needs to be some Dlc Class that looks something like this

```
public class Dlc
{
    public int Id { get; set; } //this needs to be the id of the game that is dlc

    public int GameId { get; set; } //this needs to be the id that game it is dlc for
    public virtual Game DlcFor { get; set; } //this needs to be the game object it is dlc for
}
```

I'm not even sure if what im trying to do makes sense, My mind is having trouble making the connections. Can anyone help me with this or at least suggest an alternative solution for what im trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I would just save dlc information in dlc table, define the relationship as one game to many dlcs.

```
public class Game
{   
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Dlc> Dlcs { get; set; } 
}

public class Dlc
{   
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int GameId { get; set; }
    public virtual Game game { get; set; } 
}
```

Then to check if a game has dlcs, we can just check if Dlcs collection not null or empty.
And according to my understanding, dlc usually comes with a game in real world. (please correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: i wanted to avoid this solution because the game and the dlc classes are going to be near identical when i add all the other properties (developer, publisher, release date, etc..). This was my backup solution if i couldn't figure it out.

Comment: I got what you want, but if you have one game table stores all dlc and game data and the other table manages relationship. You may end up losing some benefits like lazy loading.